# Displaying similar bars together in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a Count for each Site (which corresponds with a country), and each Site belongs to a Region. The data looks like this:

```
> summary_data
     Site Count   Region
1    Chad     5   Africa
2  Angola     1   Africa
3  France    10   Europe
4     USA     6 Americas
5 Bolivia     3 Americas
6   Chile     4 Americas
```

I would like to generate a bar graph that:

- Has a bar per country
- The bars for a region are all next to each other in the bar graph
- Per region, the bars appear in descending order
- The bars are all the same width, but the heights are all on the same scale
- Can be generalized (in particular: arbitrary regions, arbitrary countries per region)
- I do not want to use fill color to represent the region (I want to use color to represent another characteristic eventually)
- I want to have some visual representation to group the columns. For instance, having a gray background behind all the columns for the Americas region, a blue background behind all the columns for the Africa region, etc). I actually would be open to other approaches (perhaps a line at the top spanning all of Africa with "Africa" as a label or something).

Obviously each region can have a different number of country sites, and no country site spans two regions (I tried using facets but quickly realized that was not the right route). I also tried looping through all the regions to generate separate graphs per region and then put them together but that didn't quite seem the right approach either.

I have generated a graph like this (Closest I have gotten):

[image]

Using this code:

```
library("dplyr")
library(ggplot2)
sorted <- arrange(summary_data,Region,-Count)
sorted$Site <- factor(sorted$Site, levels = sorted$Site)
bar = ggplot(sorted,
   aes(
     x = Site,
     y = Count,
     fill = Region
   )) +  
  geom_col()
print(bar)
```

But this does not meet the last two requirements I set above (I specifically do not want to use fill to represent region). I started down the path of geom_rect() but did not understand the coordinate system for discrete x values rather than continuous (I did find Stackoverflow questions / answers on continuous but didn't see how to translate to this). I think having shaded rectangles behind the columns is probably the best approach, but I would appreciate any input in general approach as well as how to pull it off.

Comment: You could use `ggplot(sorted, aes(x = Region, y = Count, fill = Site)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")` which would give you grouped columns by `Region`. Further, you could fill the bars by whatever scale you want and just add the country name as a `geom_text()` to the plot.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. I get columns of different widths this way. Each Region gets the same width but the columns are fit inside that standard width (so Europe with just one Site gets the full width whereas Americas gets three columns in that same width). Is there a way of forcing a consistent bar width using this approach? Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidHobbs You have indicated that the answer below is your desired solution. You could also indicate that it was "adding value" by clicking the upper arrow, leading to more credits to the person who helped you. **Up to you, I just wanted to point out this possibility**. In some cases, the difference between the two is relevant. In this case, your comment *This is perfect!* seems to indicate that you may want to grant both kind of rewards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider defining a new panel for each region to separate them using `facet_grid`. If you want the colors to be the same, just remove the `aes(fill = Site)` argument inside `geom_bar`.

The argument `space = "free_x"` assures that the width of the bars are the same and with `scale = free` only those axis values corresponding to the specific region are shown.

```
ggplot(sorted, aes(x = Site, y = Count)) +
   geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", aes(fill = Site)) + 
   facet_grid(. ~ Region,scale="free",  space="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! That combination of space = "free_x" and scale = "free" does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped!